# JAX WS generated client gets "Unable to determine SOAP version" from new Axis2 versions

Tags: soap, jax-ws, apache-axis

We have SOAP Web Service running on Axis2-server. On client side we use JAX WS generated client. We tried to updgrade our Axis2-server from 1.6.2 to 1.7.7 and found that JAX WS client doesn't work anymore. Server returns "Unable to determine SOAP version" from Axis2-server. I searched that "Unable to determine SOAP version" error is coming from axiom library which reads type parameter from Content-Type of SOAP message.

Example of SOAP request headers:

```
Accept: application/soap+xml, multipart/related
Content-Type: multipart/related;start="<rootpart*897f69f7-8c00-461b-a0c3-08d07ea4e433@example.jaxws.sun.com>";type="application/xop+xml";boundary="uuid:897f69f7-8c00-461b-a0c3-08d07ea4e433";start-info="application/soap+xml;action=\"Authenticate\""
User-Agent: JAX-WS RI 2.2.9-b130926.1035 svn-revision#5f6196f2b90e9460065a4c2f4e30e065b245e51e
--uuid:897f69f7-8c00-461b-a0c3-08d07ea4e433
Content-Id: <rootpart*897f69f7-8c00-461b-a0c3-08d07ea4e433@example.jaxws.sun.com>
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="application/soap+xml;action=\"Authenticate\""
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in fact a bug in Apache Axiom; see [AXIOM-492](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIOM-492).